# Is there a way to copy data from 1 sheet to another with script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking to copy data from 1 sheet to another while being able to delete data from the first sheet and continuously update the second sheet with new data from sheet 1.

Sheet 1 information comes in from a form and I want to be able to delete the data every day because the calculations get slower as more data is added. Then I'd like to take that data and copy it to sheet2. All while keeping all of the past data entered.

Here's a link to the sheet (old & keep)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hLvbJL_21WWSsaEfBWj2XgKJAqlB6eIO6MwBFJAGmmI/edit?usp=sharing

Here's the Script

````
    {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var originSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("old");
      var row = sheet.getSheetByName("old").getLastRow();
      var col = sheet.getSheetByName("old").getLastColumn();
      var listToCopy = originSheet.getRange('old!A1:' + col + row);
      var destinationSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("keep");
      var row1 = sheet.getSheetByName("keep").getLastRow();
      var destinationColum = destinationSheet.getLastColumn();
      listToCopy.copyTo(destinationSheet.getRange("keep!A" + (row1 + 1)));
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName("old"), true);
      spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
    }; ```
````

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

- Given that the `old` source sheet is connected to a form it is a good idea to delete rows after the data has been pasted to the new sheet. Otherwise, the new data from the form will be appended right after the row it was entered the last time. To delete consecutive rows use [deleteRows(rowPosition, howMany)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleteRows(Integer,Integer)).
- The following script will get the current data from the source sheet, paste it to the destination sheet and remove the rows where the data was in the source sheet. I also check if there is data in the specified range to copy.

### Solution:

```
function copyTokeep() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const src_sh = ss.getSheetByName('old');
  const src_lr = src_sh.getLastRow();
  const dest_sh = ss.getSheetByName('keep');
  const src_data = src_sh.getRange('A2:K'+src_lr).getValues();
  if (src_lr>1){
  src_sh.deleteRows(2,src_lr-1);  
  dest_sh.getRange(dest_sh.getLastRow()+1,1,src_data.length,src_data[0].length).setValues(src_data);
  }
}
```